# Xamarin SIGSEGV on registering a receiver

Tags: android, xamarin

Trying to get an app running and in my MainActivity class OnCreate method I have the following:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);
    bcastRx = new BroadcastRx();
    bcastRx.Received += HandleOnBroadcastReceive;
    RegisterReceiver (bcastRx, new IntentFilter("hello"));
    ...
```

The Receiver class looks like this:

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[Register("android/content/BroadcastReceiver", DoNotGenerateAcw=true)]
class BroadcastRx : BroadcastReceiver{
    public delegate void Receive(Context c, Intent intent);
    public event Receive Received;
    public override void OnReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        if(Received != null)
            Received(c,intent);
    }
}
```

On the line that calls RegisterReceiver I get a SIGSEGV on my Nexus 5 (but not on a simulator). Backtrace:

```
[mono-rt]   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper managed-to-native) object.wrapper_native_0xb4db2c65 (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) <IL 0x0012b, 0xffffffff>
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr_JValue[] (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) <IL 0x00069, 0xffffffff>
[mono-rt]   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualObjectMethod (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) [0x00060] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:542
[mono-rt]   at Android.Content.ContextWrapper.RegisterReceiver (Android.Content.BroadcastReceiver,Android.Content.IntentFilter) [0x00089] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-21/src/generated/Android.Content.ContextWrapper.cs:2169
[mono-rt]   at client.Android.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x00038] in c:\Work\xamarin\client\Android\MainActivity.cs:31
[mono-rt]   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-21/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2380
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.47ba580a-bf7b-4507-8c4d-53e613b2dc06 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00017, 0x00043>
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper native-to-managed) object.47ba580a-bf7b-4507-8c4d-53e613b2dc06 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00023, 0xffffffff>
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt] =================================================================
[mono-rt] Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
[mono-rt] a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
[mono-rt] used by your application.
[mono-rt] =================================================================
[mono-rt] 
[libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x3e in tid 29973 (m.test.client)
```

Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong??

**edit** I've tried:

- passing a null intent filter, same result
- adding a tonne of permissions to my android manifest
- splitting up IntentFilter constructor and RegisterReceiver onto different lines. It's definitely the RegisterReceiver that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally found it; trial and error so I can't explain why it's the right answer.

```
[BroadcastReceiver]

// remove this -> [Register("android/content/BroadcastReceiver", DoNotGenerateAcw=true)]

class BroadcastRx : BroadcastReceiver{
    public delegate void Receive(Context c, Intent intent);
    public event Receive Received;
    public override void OnReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        if(Received != null)
            Received(c,intent);
    }
}
```

Magic.